# Visual Studio Code - Type Script - Unable to load tsconfig.json and packages.json schemas

Tags: angularjs, json, visual-studio-code

I'm working on an Angular front end in Visual Studio Code for an app with a C# windows service back end. After spending a few days on the back end without touching the front end, I found that Visual Studio Code would no longer automatically recompile my typescript code every time I saved. Instead, I would have to ctrl+c out of the process and run "npm start" again.

I ensured that compileOnSave was set to true in my tsconfig.json. In doing so, I notice a warning:

```
Problems loading reference 'http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig': Unable to load schema from 'http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig': Unable to to connect to http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig. Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND json.schemastore.org json.schemastore.org:80
```

I noticed a similar warning for packages.json. I'm able to load the schema on the links on Google Chrome.

What could be a possible fix? Could I download the schema and load it in Visual Studio Code manually?

Comment: Are you using a proxy? You can always download the schemas and point to them with the `"$schema"` key in your json file: `{ "$schema": "./path/to/schema.json" }`

Comment: I am actually using a proxy. I had tried re-configuring the proxy settings to allow schemastore.org to pass through but that didn't work either. However, your solution was precisely what I needed and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide more details on how to download and point to the schemas. **Update**: 1. Open https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig 2. Click on Save 3. Add a line in the existing json file `"$schema": "./yourFileLocation.json"`

Answer (score 8):

For me it wasn't the proxy blocking, but trusted domain list in VSCode.

Go to "Manage trusted domains" on Command Palette and add required url. Here we can add "http://json.schemastore.org"

This is whitelist for VSCode, as a security feature, stopping it running code from anywhere from internet.

Answer (score 5):

### Update:

Seems a network issue for me. When I set `Http: proxy` correctly it disappeared and `json schema` works well.

[image: httpproxysettings]

[image: jsonschemaworkfine]

---

Go to "Settings" > "JSON" > "Schema Download" and disabled it.

That's worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

just follow these simple steps

1. click on the Settings icon at the bottom left of your vscode
2. search for JSON
3. you should see the schema download, it should be enabled
4. just turn it off

This worked for me. [image: The first image was a before]

[image: The second image shows the text editor after]

Answer (score 3):

The solution, as pointed out by @Matt Bierner in the comment above, is to set the `"$schema"` key to direct to a local schema file (which can be downloaded from the address in the error).

The problem seems to be caused by a web proxy. Why it showed up now is still unknown.